# Where is PageFactory Class in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have .Net Core 2.2 Test project. I have installed `Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0`, `Selenium.Support 3.141.0` and `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.12600` packages. I am planning to use Page Object Model pattern however i could not find  `PageFactory` Class? Which package i need to install in order to get `PageFactory`

Answer (score 0):

i think they have removed PageFactory from .NET library
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5752